# Find out the users accessing given exe file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, exe

Is there any way of find out the users who are currently running a given `.exe` file.

For example we can find the current user of the application using `Environment.UserName`.

Does it need any modification in program or anyway of achieving this?

**Update**

Basically, I gave an exe file sitting on a network drive. I want to find out the users who are currently using the exe file.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do in better detail. If you are looking to see if a `Process` you would have to loop through all the running processes.  The problem with this, if your looking to watch the Process for certain events is that are dozens of ways to end a process, that Windows will not report back to the event as the programming ending.  You will just have reference to a `Process` that is no longer running.

Comment: If this is off topic, please let me know why? and what is the right place to ask?

Comment: I think this is much better suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - Its off topic because you asked "should this be done" and provided no code.  The information you want will be difficult to retreieve considering I know of now mechanic in Windows that will track this information.

Comment: The answer given [here](http://serverfault.com/q/424627/53676) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

as Ramhound suggested, you can use the System.Diagnostics.Process Class to monitor the processes on your system (appropriate privileges assumed)

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` will give you an array of Process objects refering to of all local processes ...

you can loop through this array and have a nested loop to go through the `Modules` Property

the `Modules` Property of a `Process` object will gibe you all `ProcessModule` objects belonging to this process (your exe file will be one of them) ... `ProcessModule.FileName` will contain the full path to the loaded module